# d3.bisector on descending array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating a simple D3 line chart and am having trouble creating the tooltip with the `d3.bisector()` function. I am looking for it to go to the Y and X axis for each value. The bisector function works fine for giving me the xData value that corresponds to the mouse coordinates but I keep getting some very strange results for the yData. I am suspecting that the problem lies in the descending nature of the yData array. Is there a way to adjust the `bisector()` function to handle descending arrays? I am looking for a solution that would work with any dataset.

```
//define the domain and range for the chart
var xScale =  d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,10]).range([0, width]);
var yScale =  d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,10]).range([height,0]);

//data for the line
var xData = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var yData = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0];

//set up the  bisector function
var bisectData= d3.bisector(function(d){return d}).left;

 // get the x and y position of the cursor and put it into the Xscale/yScale function to get the correct X and Y values from the corresponding coordinates
var x0 = xScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0])
var y0 = yScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[1])

//round the values to the nearest integer to match the original data
var x0 = Math.round(x0);
var y0 = Math.round(y0);

//get the correct index value of the relevant data array
var xIndex= bisectData(xData,x0,1);
//get the actual value from the original array using the correct index

//this work fine 
var x1 = xData[xIndex];

//this does not
var yIndex= bisectData(yData,y0,1);
var y1 = yData[yIndex];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation on [`d3.bisector()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#bisector) has you covered (emphasis mine):

> **Use a comparator rather than an accessor** if you want values to be sorted in an order different than natural order, such as **in descending rather than ascending order**.

The signature of that method allows you to pass in a comparator function which is called with the search value passed as the second argument. You can thus have a bisector for an array in descending order like so:

```
d3.bisector((d, x) => x - d).left
//              ^--- Search value
```

Have a look at the following working demo:

```js
const yData = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0];

const descBisector = d3.bisector((d, x) => x - d).left;
const yIndex = descBisector(yData, 2);

console.log(yIndex);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
```